# Hubspot API: Getting all contacts (100+)

Tags: api, loops, while-loop, hubspot

I'm trying to create one big json file with all my contacts. Since the API returns max 100 contacts I have to work with pagination.

I've found an [older topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30983587/getting-full-list-of-contacts-from-hubspot-api/32744452) on this but this uses an external [repo](https://github.com/HubSpot/haPiHP). I've found a [newer repo](https://github.com/ryanwinchester/hubspot-php), but can't get that one to work. Best case, I don't use an external lib because I need such a small piece of code.

I've tried the following code, but it keeps on loading. My guess is that the variables don't update. What am I doing wrong?

```
<?php


echo '<pre>';
function getData($offset = 0){

$properties = "&property=email&property=firstname&property=funnel&property=hs_lead_status&property=start_session";
$apikey = "xxxx-xx-xx";
$feed_url = "https://api.hubapi.com/contacts/v1/lists/all/contacts/recent?hapikey=". $apikey.  $properties.'&vidOffset='.$offset;

$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => $feed_url,
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "cache-control: no-cache"
  ),
));
$response = curl_exec($curl);
$data = json_decode($response);

return $data; //return the results for use
}

$allData = array();




$offset = 0;
$hasMore = true;

while ($hasMore === true) {

    $response = getData( $offset );
    $allData[] = $response;


    $offset = $response->{'vid-offset'};
    $hasMore = $response->{'has-more'};

    var_dump( $hasMore );
    $hasMore = false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One thing that I can think of is that your loop doesn't take into consideration the fact that HubSpot only allows 10 request per second (see [here](https://developers.hubspot.com/apps/api_guidelines)) - your loop might be exceeding that and as such causing the issues. You should add the following code just before the end of your while loop (this will sleep the script for 0.1 seconds):

```
usleep(100000);
```

Additionally, it might be a better and a cleaner idea to use a PHP API library such as [this one](https://github.com/ryanwinchester/hubspot-php/blob/master/src/Resources/Contacts.php).